# Cannot pass a subdocument's property as a filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In this object.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "63a48f12a9731cfd8a64b0b1",
            "item_name": "addidas shoes",
            "__v": 0,
            "rating": [
                {
                    "_id": "63a48fd51fb70775d216eb87",
                    "rate": 1,
                    "user_id": "6398a1a157d6146413b23b43"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to update the rating property if a user_id inside of it already exists, else, add a new object into it.

I created the following API to achieve this.

```
    const addRating = async (req, res) => {
  const { rate, user_id, item_id } = req.body;
  const ratingInfo = new RatingDB.Rating({
    rate: rate, // 7
    user_id: user_id, // 63a48fd51fb70775d216eb87
    item_id: item_id, // 63a48f12a9731cfd8a64b0b1
  });

  try {
    const result = await itemDB.item.updateOne(
      { _id: item_id, rating: { user_id: user_id } },
      {
        $push: {
          rating: { _id: ratingInfo._id, rate: rate, user_id: user_id },
        },
      },
      { upsert: true}
    );

    console.log(result);
    res.json({ message: "success" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

as you can see, I have added two filters on it. One for item_id and the user_id from the rating property. With these filters though, nothings logs on the console and the response is

```
{
    "message": {
        "index": 0,
        "code": 2
    }
}
```

I have tried several ways of accesing the sub document to pass it as a filter like

```
{ _id: item_id, rating.user_id: user_id }
or { _id: item_id, rating[user_id]: user_id }
```

but I'm getting unexpected tokken error on it.

Also tried `{ _id: item_id, "rating.user_id": user_id }` but it gives the same JSON response.

**Items schema:**

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  item_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  rating: {
    type:Array,
    required: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm sure that the problem arises from the filters parameter on the updateOne method of mongodb as it appends the object properly into the ratings array of the item with the right id when I make the filter as the item id only.

`const result = await itemDB.item.updateOne(
      { _id: item_id} `

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is what is called an [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query in MongoDB. Specifically, you should make the following changes to your `where` object in the `updateOne` query:

```js
const result = await itemDB.item.updateOne(
      { _id: item_id, rating: {$elemMatch: { user_id: user_id }} },
      // update object for matched documents
    );
```

Comment: I tried it to hit the endpoint and this is what it responds with 
`{
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { _id: 1 },
  keyValue: {
    _id: ObjectId {
      [Symbol(id)]: Buffer(12) [Uint8Array] [
         99, 165,  99,  70,  33,
        159,   6, 134, 214, 147,
        112, 143
      ]
    }
  },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}`
error:
return callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(res.writeErrors[0]));
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: 638f51799ece730074d3fe2b_StoreDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('63a56346219f0686d693708f') }